# Would it make more sense to build project from package.json to ensure that we have wanted versions of dependencies?

Tags: angular, deployment, build, package.json

This is actually research or more technical question. Could not find relevant post.

I am deploying my angular app on server. Just wanted to know what is the best practice to build angular app. Is it common/good prectice to build the app by putting ng build in package.json file to maintain dependency versions instead of running ng build directly on cli. If its a bad practice(build from package.json), can someone expalin the reason please?

*EDIT

If i add below lines in package.json

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "postinstall": "ng build ..."
 },
```

will it use version that is declarated as dependency in package.json (even if global version is different)?

Comment: The 2 build procedures you have mentioned, they both do same things.

Comment: `ng build` is the `angular-cli`'s build command. Either you put it in `package.json` or run in `command prompt` or `console`, it does the same thing.

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani So there will be no issue with dependencies versions whatever the method i will use?

Comment: Dependency versions will be dependent on the versions you mention in the `devDependency` section in `package.json`. Make sure you have entries in  like  `"@angular/cli": "1.4.9",`, not `"@angular/cli": "~1.4.9",`, not `"@angular/cli": "^1.4.9",`

Comment: It means whatever the method will be used for build. It always installs versions specified in package.json.